# How to get image form RSS feed from a FeedBurner URL?

Tags: android, rss

I'm trying to get the image from a `FeedBurner` URL but I'm not able to accomplish this.

EDITED:

This is the [URL](http://androidheadlines.com/feed).

I'm noticing the image is inside the < content:encoded > tag.

Also im having trouble in retrieving image from this [URL](http://feeds.feedburner.com/AndroidNewsGoogleAndroidForums).

which im not able to pull information out of it.

Here is my code:

```
class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private Post currentPost = new Post();

StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) {

    chars = new StringBuffer();


    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("thumbnail")) {          
        String thumbnail = atts.getValue("url");    
        currentPost.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")
            && currentPost.getTitle() == null) {
        currentPost.setTitle(chars.toString());

    }
    String pubd;
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")
            && currentPost.getPubDate() == null) {

        currentPost.setPubDate(chars.toString());
        Home.DATE_1.add(chars.toString()); 
    }

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link") && currentPost.getUrl() == null) {

        currentPost.setUrl(chars.toString());
    }

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        FragmentView.PostList.add(currentPost);

        currentPost = new Post();
        }

}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}
```

}

I'm using this handler to get the information from the RSS feed. Everything is working fine for other feeds but when it is a `FeedBurner` URL I can't seem to get the images.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the URL for the image

```
<media:content url="http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/11/SC20121102-150432.png" medium="image">
<media:title type="html">SC20121102-150432</media:title>
<media:thumbnail url="http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/11/SC20121102-150432-150x150.png" />
```

After you got the image convert it to a bitmap, sample code:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        //TODO on error
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit:

First read your HTML file, then use regex for obtaining the src url wihtin the IMG tags

regex:

```
String imgRegex = "<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";
```

Use the imgregex value to get the bitmap image.

Comment: Im sorry the URL i put is not the one i was talking about. I have edited the post.

Comment: Doens't matter what source URL you use, as long it contains IMG tags for the images. see my edit for obtaining the src from the IMG tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the image from the content via regex but it's preferred if you used an XmlPullParser instead.

This library has a great example of that:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

This code snippet is found in the Rss2Parser.java file of that library and it accomplishes exactly what you need. Simply pass the content as the parameter.

/**

```
 * Pulls an image URL from an encoded String.

 *

 * @param encoded The String which to extract an image URL from.

 * @return The first image URL found on the encoded String. May return an

 * empty String if none were found.

 */

private String pullImageLink(String encoded) {

    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();


        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(encoded));

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && "img".equals(xpp.getName())) {

                int count = xpp.getAttributeCount();

                for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {

                    if (xpp.getAttributeName(x).equalsIgnoreCase("src"))

                        return xpp.getAttributeValue(x).replaceAll("-110x52", "");

                }

            }

            eventType = xpp.next();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        log(TAG, "Error pulling image link from description!\n" + e.getMessage(), Log.WARN);

    }


    return "";

}
```